# Yii: Returns 404 page on saving form model

Tags: php, yii

I don't know what happened but at some point my form submission to save the model Students is failing. For example when I submit the form for a Student, it used to redirect to /student/33 which shows the student I just created but now it's showing 404 error. There's no error or stacktrace thrown.

How can I debug this situation? When I go to /student/22 it shows up fine. I think it must have been some change I made but can't figure out how to debug this. All I did was change the date format.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the form action is pointing to the right url. Use the **action** key as part of the form -

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'add-form',
        'action'=>$this->createUrl('site/student',array('id'=>$id)),
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
        'enableClientValidation'=>false,
        'clientOptions'=>array(
          'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
          'validateOnChange'=>false,
          'validateOnType'=>true,
        ),
      )); ?>
```

Comment: makes sense I was making some changes with the form widget calendar picker (I was trying to change yyyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yyyy format). I would like to know if I can get Yii to throw some error stack ideally.

Comment: You could always look at the application log in the runtime for more info

Comment: where is this application log file?

Comment: @KimJongWoo - wouldn't looking at the network tab be enough to indicate whether the url redirected is right. In your case the action route you requested using the form probably doesn't exist due to a URL mismatch hence the redirection to 404. read up http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging to fill up on your last question.

Comment: @themosquitokiller when I go to the admin view it's there, but when I click view it throws 404

Comment: so it shows when viewed as admin but not as another user? have you checked your acl restrictions?

Comment: @themosquitokiller I generated these using the giix model and crud generator. Everything was working fine until an hour ago when it wouldn't show the view...im trying to figure this out but there's no log or anything that is produced. I'm going to look for the application log file and start from there